# CI: (Count Rows) with same ID

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
foodorders

foodorders_id    foodorders_price    foodorders_status
1                   100                     1
2                   20                      1
3                   30                      1


foodorders_detail

foodorders_detail_id(AI,PK)      foodorders_id    foodorders_foodname    foodorders_lines
1                                       1               burgers                 1
2                                       1               fries                   2
3                                       1               chips                   3
4                                       2               chips                   1
5                                       3               drinks                  1
5                                       3               bars                    2
```

What i want : check how many rows with same foodorders_id and returns to controller

What i tried :

```
$this->db->select('foodorders.foodorders_price,foodorders.status,COUNT(foodorders_detail.foodorders_lines');
$this->db->from('foodorders');
$this->db->join('foodorders_detail', 'foodorders_detail.foodorders_id = sales.foodorders_id', 'left');
```

Comment: you want count of `foodorders_lines` of same `foodorders_id` ?

Comment: @KUMAR yeah , need to count foodorders_line with same foodorders_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add foodorders.foodorders_id to your select columns and add group by to your query and then get result as object or array:
hint: use alias to shorten your code.

```
    $this->db->select('foodorders.foodorders_id,foodorders.foodorders_price,foodorders.status,COUNT(foodorders_detail.foodorders_lines)');
    $this->db->from('foodorders');
    $this->db->join('foodorders_detail', 'foodorders_detail.foodorders_id = foodorders.foodorders_id', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('foodorders.foodorders_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```